# malformed line in source list

Tags: apt, updates

I'm trying to install library using (sudo apt-get install python-tk )
this error appears

```
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Malformed line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gazebo-stable.list (type)
```

and i don't know what should be written in this file
currently this is written in it

```
deb 
http://packages.osrfoundation.org/gazebo/ubuntu-stable focal 
main
```

Comment: You can simply remove that file.

Comment: Just take the line breaks out, all the text should appear on one line.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm not sure if it's important file or not

Comment: @OrganicMarble the link has a different problem but removing the line breaks helped thank you